# WQL/SCCM - Comparing version numbers correctly (less than...)

Tags: sccm, wql, version-numbering

I'm having a problem with this part of a SCCM WQL query looking for "less than version 75.0.3770.80":

```
... where SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.Version < "75.0.3770.80"
```

If i'm not mistaken this is the good old problem seen before in other scenarios (file names for example) where it will return objects with version number :

```
75.0.3770.142
```

Because in it's logic "of course" `.142` is "less than" `.80` because `.1` is less than `.8`. It doesn't treat it as "142 versus 80" but "1 versus 8"

Is there any way I can work around this? I'm getting a lot of false positives with this query and need to filter them out. If it was straight Powershell I could cast it as [version] but in SCCM, is it at all possible to do this comparison?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using `SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.Version < "75.0.3770"`

Answer (score 1):

If only the last part of the version number is different, we could use the following one.

```
... where SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.Version like "75.0.3770.[1-7][0-9]"
or ... like "75.0.3770.[0-9]"
```

Best Regards,
Ray

Comment: Ah, good tip with the brackets! However here it's needed to get all versions less than "75.0.3770.80", this wouldn't work

Answer (score 0):

This goes wrongs if the first version nr reach 100.
Better something like this

```
SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.Version like "75.0.%" and
SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.Version < "75.0.3770
```